# Query in DB casts to bigint unnecessarily

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a query in linq that looks like:

```
IEnumerable<long> ids = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(x => (long)x).ToList();
    this.tableA.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.id))
    .Take(1000)
    .ToList();
```

The resulting query casts each of the values in `IEnumerable<long> ids`
to bigint and I don't understand why, My tableA Model in my code uses long for the id and the table in the DB uses bigint for the id

This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id]
    FROM [dbo].[tableA] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[id] IN (cast(1 as bigint), cast(2 as bigint), cast(3 as bigint), cast(4 as bigint), cast(5 as bigint))
```

Anyone knows why this casting happens?

Comment: Which DB vendor and which ORM?

Comment: Im using Microsoft Sql Server and linq

Comment: How are the columns defined in the database?  The results are being mapped to the type defined in the database.

Comment: LINQ is not an ORM. It's a syntax for query expressions that an ORM can use to build queries. Are you using Entity Framework [Core]? (That would be my guess based on the "[Extent1]" table alias.)

Comment: LINQ isn't an ORM, but anyway, you'd expect the ORM to cast each number to `bigint` considering `long` can contain 8 byte numbers.

Comment: yea, Im using EF. is there a way to avoid this casting? (I understand casting disrupts retrieval with indexing?)

Comment: The casting is unimportant. They get reduced to bigint literals long before the query executes. There's no cost in execution time.

Comment: What are you converting each `int` into a `long` in your `Select`?

Comment: As Johnathan said, [`long` in C# maps to `bigint` in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). If you don't want the cast in SQL, don't cast your values to `long` in C#.

Comment: Is `tableA's` `id` column a `bigint`?

Comment: If `id` is `bigint`, then passing `x.id` (a long) to `ids.Contains` would be a compiler error if `ids` has `int`s. That would be a reason for casting to `long`

Comment: The model in the code has ```long id```, the column in the DB is bigint.
So I need to do the select so the code will compile

Comment: Okay, so as I said, the cast in the generated SQL is unimportant. EF is being pedantic. Ignore it. Move on.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to Entity Framework Core Tutorials at [Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx), `long` is considered and dealt as `bigint` due to both being a Int64 type. If you want to use sql data type `int` you should declare your properties as `int` in c#. This is the case for other ORM's as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you think simply, It is the direct convertion from SQL to C#. SQL **bigint** directly convert to **System.Int64** in C#.

In C#:

```
int = System.Int32
long = System.Int64
short = System.Int16
```

Please check tke SQL server data type mapping documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql-server-data-type-mappings?view=sql-server-ver15

Therefore, you will get **long** type in the ORM and **bigint** in the SQL table.